# JavaScript onClick handler does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a question regarding Javascript.

Below are my codes.

1) search.html

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkSubmit(thisForm) {
        if (thisForm.last.value == '') {
            alert('Please Enter Last Name');
            return false;
        }
    }

    function lookup(inputString) {
        if (inputString.length == 0) {
            $('#suggestions').hide();
        } else {
            $.post("autocom.jsp", {
                queryString: "" + inputString + ""
            }, function (data) {
                $('#suggestions').show();
                $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
            });
        }
    }

    function fill(thisValue) {
        $('#inputString').val(thisValue);
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .suggestionsBox {
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
        left: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        border: 0px solid black;
        background-color: white;
        font-size: 75%;
    }
    .suggestionList {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    .suggestionList div {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="search.jsp" onsubmit="return checkSubmit (this);">
    Enter Last Name:
    <input type="text" name="last" value="" id="inputString" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
        <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<form method="post" action="home.html">
    <input type="submit" id="button" value="Back To Home" mouseover="colour();">
</form>
```

1) autocom.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*" %><% 
response.setContentType("text/html");%><%
String str=request.getParameter("queryString");
int k = 0;
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/jsptest";
Connection con;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "Dummy123");  // Get a Connection to the database
Statement stm = con.createStatement();
String sql = "SELECT last FROM employees WHERE last LIKE '" +str+  "%'"; //Add the data into the database
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);    
while (rs.next()) {
out.println("<div onclick='fill("+rs.getString(1)+");'>"+rs.getString(1)+"</div>");
}%>
```

Here is briefly how it works. After a value is inputted in the "Enter Last Name" field of the search.html file, the javascript lookup function  takes data from the autocom.jsp file and outputs it through the callback function(data) in the element of the search.html file with id=autoSuggestionsList.

I am actually trying to write codes for autocomplete for the field "Enter Last Name" of the html form.

When the callback function(data) outputs data within the element with id=autoSuggestionsList after the letter m is type into the "Enter Last Name" field, it is outputted in the following form, with html codes:

```
<div onclick='fill(Mattison);'>Mattison</div>
<div onclick='fill(McFagan);'>McFagan</div>
<div onclick='fill(Murphy);'>Murphy</div>
<div onclick='fill(Mux);'>Mux</div>
```

I have 2 simple questions:

1) Why is it that when I click on a div element which has the onclick attribute, the field "Enter Last Name" is not automatically filled with the name I clicked on? Is there a problem with the way I wrote the Javascript fill function?

2) How can I use the mouseover event handler to highlight the name in the drop-down list which has the cursor over it? I have tried several codes, but it does not work.

Thanks for reading

Regards

Comment: try `onclick='fill.bind(null, "Mattison")'`

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you are missing quotation marks in the argument bing passed in Fill function...

```
    <div onclick='fill("Mattison");'>Mattison</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man...However, if you look at the code: out.println("<div onclick='fill("+rs.getString(1)+");'>"+rs.getString(1)+"</div>"); there is no point in using quotation marks since rs.getString(1) is a string variable. Should I add additional quotation marks?